# New iPhone transfer did not bring AirTag info from old phone

Tags: iphone, migration, migration-assistant, airtag

I just got a new iPhone SE 3rd generation to replace my iPhone SE 2nd generation. I just when through the automated migration process of transferring over all info while holding the phones close. Seemed to have worked well.

But I was surprised to find that the *Items* tab of the *Find My* app knows none of my AirTags.

Is there a way to bring over those AirTag registrations? Or must I re-register AirTags with the new phone from scratch?

If re-registering is required, is the proper route that is described in Apple Support page, [*How to reset your AirTag*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212251), where you remove, replace, and press the battery inside the AirTag five times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Wait

Just wait. It takes a long while for the iPhone to retrieve all information from iCloud. Makes sure you leave your iPhone connected to the internet.

Some items such as the AirTag registrations may take like an hour to appear.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with a new iPhone 14. The attached AirTags were not showing up in Find My. I was about to re-register all the tags again, but then I tried a hard-reset of the phone. (I hadn't rebooted it since I had set it up, and transferred the data from my old iPhone). After the reset, all the AirTags were showing again in Find My. Now I have to go and return all the AirTags to their hiding spots.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Actually my problem was impatience. The AirTag registrations eventually appeared on my phone. Your Answer prompted me to post my own Answer with that fact.